# Specify java version by project when exporting JAR via Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have successfully configured java.configuration.runtimes in the settings of VSCode in order to specify what version of Java I want to use to compile a project, and can successfully export a compiled JAR.  What I need to know is, if I have multiple projects that I want to export using different versions of Java, is this an option?

It appears the java.configuration.runtimes setting is at the IDE level and not at the project level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, you can specify java version when exporting projects as jars via the setting:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk11",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-14",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-14",
    "default": true
  },
]
```

The setting **default：true**'s location will decide the java version when you compile the project.

With the above setting, i create a project, when pressing F5 to compile and run:
[image]

you can see the java extension did use jdk14 to compile the .java file, and turn to the directory of the words yellow underlined, there is a .class file.

Using the command:

```
javap -verbose .class
```

there will be a lot of information showed and the value of **major version** also represents java version:
[image]

the major version of JDK11 is 55, and the one of JDK14 is 58, so the setting does work. You can add it in User setting, then export projects as jars with different java version.

Comment: Thanks.  My question though is, if you define which configuration is "true" in the user settings, how can I compile project A with 1.7 and project B with 1.8 for example?  Won't it always default to 1.7 if that's marked as true?

Comment: @a344254, Yes, default jdk will always be your project compile version. so set the 1.7 as the default, then compile project A. after it has been finished, transfer the default value to 1.8, then compile project B. Do you mean to compile these two projects at the same time with different JDK? I'm afraid it couldn't access.

Comment: I was hoping it would be like NetBeans or Eclipse where you could specify at a project level what JDK to use as opposed to at the IDE level

Comment: Actually, VS Code is just a text editor, but when extension installed, code and language server are supported. The setting User and Workspace can be seen as global and the current directory, also as IDE and project. but the setting "java.configuration.runtimes" only works in User setting.